# Is there a rule-of-thumb for how to divide a dataset into training and validation sets?

Tags: machine-learning

Is there a rule-of-thumb for how to best divide data into training and validation sets? Is an even 50/50 split advisable? Or are there clear advantages of having more training data relative to validation data (or vice versa)? Or is this choice pretty much application dependent?

I have been mostly using an 80% / 20% of training and validation data, respectively, but I chose this division without any principled reason. Can someone who is more experienced in machine learning advise me?

Comment: If you do not have too much data available, consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Jackknife

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Machine learning (ML) theory questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291009/do-pure-machine-learning-questions-belong-to-stack-overflow/291015#291015) - [gift-wrap candidate for Cross-Validated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404799/lets-gift-wrap-our-good-machine-learning-theory-questions-for-cross-validated?noredirect=1#comment822113_404799)

Comment: Is it possible to migrate this and the answers to Cross-Validated?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

There are two competing concerns: with less training data, your parameter estimates have greater variance. With less testing data, your performance statistic will have greater variance. Broadly speaking you should be concerned with dividing data such that neither variance is too high, which is more to do with the absolute number of instances in each category rather than the percentage.

If you have a total of 100 instances, you're probably stuck with cross validation as no single split is going to give you satisfactory variance in your estimates. If you have 100,000 instances, it doesn't really matter whether you choose an 80:20 split or a 90:10 split (indeed you may choose to use less training data if your method is particularly computationally intensive).

Assuming you have enough data to do proper held-out test data (rather than cross-validation), the following is an instructive way to get a handle on variances:

1. Split your data into training and testing (80/20 is indeed a good starting point)
2. Split the *training* data into training and validation (again, 80/20 is a fair split).
3. Subsample random selections of your training data, train the classifier with this, and record the performance on the validation set
4. Try a series of runs with different amounts of training data: randomly sample 20% of it, say, 10 times and observe performance on the validation data, then do the same with 40%, 60%, 80%. You should see both greater performance with more data, but also lower variance across the different random samples
5. To get a handle on variance due to the size of test data, perform the same procedure in reverse. Train on all of your training data, then randomly sample a percentage of your *validation* data a number of times, and observe performance. You should now find that the mean performance on small samples of your validation data is roughly the same as the performance on all the validation data, but the variance is much higher with smaller numbers of test samples

Comment: Thanks, this is also very helpful! I will give it a try. FYI, I have about 6000 instances of training data. I am using SVM, so performance is somewhat of an issue.

Comment: FWIW, variance in the performance can be calculated by classifying all the instances once, scoring the decisions as to whether they are correct or not, and then sampling these *decisions* instead of test instances to produce the effects of using different test set sizes

Comment: And 6000 instances should be enough that the differences between using 10% or 20% for testing won't be that great (you can confirm this using the method I describe)

Comment: Hi again. I'm a little confused in point #5. You said "then randomly sample a percentage of your *validation* data a number of times". Did you mean to see *test* data instead? If I understand right, I should divide my data first into training and test datasets, then further portion off some of my training dataset into a validation dataset. So in step 5, if I am measuring the variance on my test data, shouldn't I randomly sample populations from my test data? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The point is that while you're playing around with parameters, observing the effects of changing things, you should be using your *validation* data to test on. If you start looking at your test data, and choosing strategies based on what gives you the highest score on that, you'll get an inflated sense of your method's performance. When all your parameters are set and decisions made, *then* run on your test data. This lets you know what sort of performance you'll get on genuinely new, unobserved data (which is probably what you're interested in!)

Comment: @BenAllison Thanks for the super-interesting reply. So, would using alternative strategies such as training set = 50% and test set = 50%, or inverted proportions such as 20% / 80% always a bad choice? Why?

Comment: @BenAllison I want to use a dataset and only one paper is published so far with that dataset and the author said that he randomly selected the images for training, validation, and testing which is 40-60.

Is case if I randomly select then how can I ensure that all the object classes are equally distributed?

Comment: You're looking for something called a stratified sample. If you're in Python scikit learn has this as a built in feature: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold

Comment: What about if you have 44k samples?

Answer (score 71):

You'd be surprised to find out that 80/20 is quite a commonly occurring ratio, often referred to as the [Pareto principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle). It's usually a safe bet if you use that ratio.

However, depending on the training/validation methodology you employ, the ratio may change. For example: if you use 10-fold cross validation, then you would end up with a validation set of 10% at each fold.

There has been some research into [what is the proper ratio between the training set and the validation set](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.33.1337&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> The fraction of patterns reserved for the validation set should be
>   inversely proportional to the square root of the number of free
>   adjustable parameters.

In their conclusion they specify a formula:

> Validation set (v) to training set (t) size ratio, v/t, scales like
>   ln(N/h-max), where N is the number of families of recognizers and
>   h-max is the largest complexity of those families.

What they mean by complexity is:

> Each family of recognizer is characterized by its complexity, which
>   may or may not be related to the [VC-dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension), the description
>   length, the number of adjustable parameters, or other measures of
>   complexity.

Taking the first rule of thumb (i.e.validation set should be inversely proportional to the square root of the number of free adjustable parameters), you can conclude that if you have 32 adjustable parameters, the square root of 32 is ~5.65, the fraction should be 1/5.65 or 0.177 (v/t). Roughly 17.7% should be reserved for validation and 82.3% for training.

Comment: The paper, for those that might have trouble loading it like myself (not sure why), is: "A scaling law for the validation-set training-set ratio size" (I. Guyon, 1996, Unpublished Technical Report, AT&T Bell Laboratories).

Comment: Does the rule of thumb make sense? If you have two adjustable parameters then the ratio is 0.77, meaning that you would use 77% for validation. Imho the problem is the free parameter definition. For a linear SVM you can set the penalty parameter C for the error term which is one parameter, but the complexity is higher Dimension+1 for an SVM.

Comment: Then should my test size be 1 if I have a neural network..?

Comment: I am not able to reach the paper. Could someone send me or share the DOI number? @theforestecologist

Answer (score 58):

Last year, I took Prof: Andrew Ng’s online machine learning course. His recommendation was:

**Training**: 60%

**Cross-validation**: 20%

**Testing**: 20%

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/lecture/cxG1s/train-dev-test-sets `in the modern big data era, where, for example, you might have a million examples in total, then the trend is that your dev (cross validation) and test sets have been becoming a much smaller percentage of the total.` He suggests it could be 99.5:0.25:0.25.

Comment: exactly. Moreover, there's some problem with this post. Maybe the author wanted to write "Validation"? Cross-validation is a different thing.

Answer (score 25):

Well, you should think about one more thing.

If you have a really big dataset, like 1,000,000 examples, split 80/10/10 may be unnecessary, because 10% = 100,000 examples may be just too much for just saying that model works fine.

Maybe 99/0.5/0.5 is enough because 5,000 examples can represent most of the variance in your data and you can easily tell that model works good based on these 5,000 examples in test and dev.

Don't use 80/20 just because you've heard it's ok. Think about the purpose of the test set.

Comment: 0.5% in the validation set could be enough but I'd argue that you are taking a big and unnecessary risk since you don't know is enough or not. Your training can easily go wrong if you are using a too small validation set, but it's almost impossible for it to go wrong by using a large validation set.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Is there a way or a statistical method to at least estimate the minimum amount of dataset that contains most of variance in data?

Comment: Not that I know of and intuitively I don't think such a metric could make sense. A priori you don't know what features are the most relevant so computing those features' variance is of course impossible. The only safe bet is to make the validation set large enough, for some definition of "large enough."

Comment: With 1 000 000 data points, 1% is 10000 and with 50k points 20% is 10000. You just really need to estimate whether the variance in your data is covered by these 10 000 examples. It depends on the task. It's much more important to select test examples (f.e. stratify according to labels) than to have a large non-representative test set. Don't use 80/20 just because you've heard it's ok. Think about the purpose of test set.

Comment: You underestimating the importance of the validation and test sets. If you have 1,000,000 examples it's really a shame to use only 5,000 for testing as you usually have a lot of variance in the data and therefore using too few validation/testing samples lead to a wrong model selection.

Comment: Usually doesn't mean always. I'm not saying to use 0.5%. I'm saying one should think what is the variance in the data and how many examples do you need to cover it. I usually do experiments with a few shuffled test sets of the same size, to prove 0.5% or 20% scores are or are not stable, independent from the fortunate/unfortunate split.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a 63.2% / 36.8% is a reasonable choice. The reason would be that if you had a total sample size *n* and wanted to randomly sample with replacement (a.k.a. re-sample, as in the statistical bootstrap) *n* cases out of the initial *n*, the probability of an individual case being selected in the re-sample would be approximately 0.632, provided that *n* is not too small, as explained here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88993/16263

For a sample of *n*=250, the probability of an individual case being selected for a re-sample to 4 digits is 0.6329.
For a sample of *n*=20000, the probability is 0.6321.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the data at hand. If you have considerable amount of data then 80/20 is a good choice as mentioned above. But if you do not Cross-Validation with a 50/50 split might help you a lot more and prevent you from creating a model over-fitting your training data.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have less data, I suggest to try 70%, 80% and 90% and test which is giving better result. In case of 90% there are chances that for 10% test you get poor accuracy.

Comment: hi, is there any base (research papers) for your suggestions here "In the case of 90% there are chances that for 10% test you get poor accuracy."? Because I think my case falls into this category. TQ