# 4 fold cross validation | Caffe

Tags: cross-validation, caffe

So I trying to perform a 4-fold cross validation on my training set. I have divided my training data into four quarters. I use three quarters for training and one quarter for validation. I repeat this three more times till all the quarters are given a chance to be the validation set, atleast once.

Now after training I have four caffemodels. I test the models on my validation sets. I am getting different accuracy in each case. How should I proceed from here? Should I just choose the model with the highest accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a late reply, but in any case...
The short answer is that, if the performances of the four models are similar and good enough, then you re-train the model on all the data available, because you don't want to waste any of them.

The n-fold cross validation is a practical technique to get some insights on the learning and generalization properties of the model you are trying to train, when you don't have a lot of data to start with. You can find details everywhere on the web, but I suggest the open-source book [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/), Chapter 5.

The general rule says that after you trained your n models, you average the prediction error (MSE, accuracy, or whatever) to get a general idea of the performance of that particular model (in your case maybe the network architecture and learning strategy) on that dataset.
The main idea is to assess the models learned on the training splits checking if they have an acceptable performance on the validation set. If they do not, then your models probably overfitted tha training data. If both the errors on training and validation splits are high, then the models should be reconsidered, since they don't have predictive capacity.

In any case, I would also consider the [advice of Yoshua Bengio](https://www.quora.com/Is-cross-validation-heavily-used-in-Deep-Learning-or-is-it-too-expensive-to-be-used/answer/Yoshua-Bengio?srid=ipgD) who says that for the kind of problem deep learning is meant for, you usually have enough data to simply go with a training/test split. In this case [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610074/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-how-to-divide-a-dataset-into-training-and-validatio) could be useful to you.